# Strange error with ruby module usage

Tags: ruby, module

I have the following script:

start.rb

```
require 'csv'
require_relative "modules/01httpserver"
01httpserver.helloworld("something")
```

In the folder /modules I have the file 01httpserver.rb the code in that file is as follows:

01httpserver.rb

```
module 01httpserver
  def self.helloworld(name)
    puts "Hello, #{name}"
  end
end
```

So when I run start.rb I get the following error:

```
start.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
01httpserver.helloworld("something")
            ^
```

What's causing this?  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I don't think class / module / variable names can start with a digit.

Comment: Obviously there's more code in the start.rb file than I included, so disregard the line number of the error "26". :-)

Comment: Okay so I changed the module to just httpserver and changed all references, but it's now saying "cis.rb:2:in `require_relative': /Users/marklalich/Desktop/Scripts/Ruby/CIS/modules/httpserver.rb:1: class/module name must be CONSTANT (SyntaxError)
 from cis.rb:2:in `<main>'"

Comment: A module / classname has to start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Awesome, so the filename can start with a digit and I can require it as such, but I must call the module inside the module file "Httpserver".  Thank you all!!

Comment: Ruby does not require a filename to be the same as the module it defines. In fact, you can multiple classes / modules in the same file. And of course Ruby does not have anything to say about the allowed names of file names of an OS :)

Answer (score 2):

The variables and constants cannot start with a digit. So trying to run

```
1a = 10
```

will throw the same error.

Coincidentally, `0XXXX` denotes an octal number, so that `010` evaluates to 8.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, variable/class names cannot begin with numbers, so `01httpserver` is an invalid variable name.